# Evenly spaced loop increments in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Lets say I want to go from -8 to -1.05.
However, I would like to include -8 and -1.05 as a value to be used.

Say I use an increment of 0.5 for example, the last value used will be -1.5, not -1.05.

Is there some formula I can use to get an increment value that will make the last input -1.05?

Comment: I just used linspace(-8,-1.05,num increment) and it worked

Comment: Conor, `linspace` is indeed the right approach. Consider writing an answer to your question.